# MS RMS SQL Server Database error

Tags: sql-server

We have had an issue with our RMS_Headquarters(front end application to access database) database running on SQL Express 2005.

After checking all the event log on server, I came across few errors related to hard disk and sqlserver.

**disk error snapshot**

**sqlexpress error**

I have executed two commands as follows to find out any error in disk or on sql database.

**chkdsk**  : System found bad sectors on hard disk I ran this code without /f to just get the information.

**DBCC CHECKDB with ALL_ERRORMSGS, NO_INFOMSGS**    and the outcome was as below.

I ran chkdsk /f to resolve the disk error. This command helped to get hq database up and running (application was working fine from this point). I also ran DBCC CHECKDB with ALL_ERRORMSGS, NO_INFOMSGS on sql server to check database status. DBCC executed with few errors, please see below.

```
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 1429580131, index ID 1, partition ID 72057598907908096, alloc unit ID 72057598960730112 (type In-row data): Page (1:235150) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8941, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 1429580131, index ID 1, partition ID 72057598907908096, alloc unit ID 72057598960730112 (type In-row data), page (1:235150). Test (sorted [i].offset <= m_freeData) 
failed. Slot 0, offset 0xffff is invalid.
Msg 8976, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 1429580131, index ID 1, partition ID 72057598907908096, alloc unit ID 72057598960730112 (type In-row data). Page (1:235150) was not seen in the scan although its 
parent (1:306430) and previous (1:235149) refer to it. Check any previous errors.
Msg 8978, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 1429580131, index ID 1, partition ID 72057598907908096, alloc unit ID 72057598960730112 (type In-row data). Page (1:235151) is missing a reference from previous page 
(1:235150). Possible chain linkage problem.
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 4 consistency errors in table 'TenderEntry' (object ID 1429580131).
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 4 consistency errors in database 'RMS_Headquarters'.
repair_allow_data_loss is the minimum repair level for the errors found by DBCC CHECKDB (RMS_Headquarters).
```

**System Information:**

- OS:         Windows Server 2003 R2
- SQL Server:         SQL Server 2005 (9.0.4035)

I have a backup from Sunday(20th April 2015) evening, that backup doesn’t report any error.

Please advise me what should be done in this matter:
(a) restore the database from a backup dated 20th April 2015 (what data from 21st onwards will be lost) 
(b) continue with this database and ignore the ‘tenderentry’ table errors

Your help will be appreciated.

Regards
Pratik

Comment: it did not allow me to post images

Comment: **chkdsk : System found bad sectors on hard disk** This means you need to replace or fix your disk before you bother trying to restore the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a)restore the database from a backup dated 20th April 2015 (what data from 21st onwards will be lost)

Yes Data will be lost because your backup was last updated on 20 April 2015.

(b)continue with this database and ignore the ‘tenderentry’ table errors

Personally I will not suggest this because it might be possible that you will have a bigger corruption issues in future. Fixing corruption as an earlier stage should be on priority. It helps to maintain database health.

And please not run DBCC CHECKDB with repair_allow_data_loss without knowing the effect of it.